# silverstripe dataobject searchable

Tags: content-management-system, silverstripe

I´m trying to have certain DataObjects (News) displayed in the default SearchResult Page. So the result should display normal Pages and News.

Is there an easy way to accomplish that in Silverstripe 3?
Or is it recommended to code it completely custom - I mean a custom controller/action which handles the search request and creates a result list, which I display then in a custom template?

I found this, but obviously search is disabled right now:
https://github.com/arambalakjian/DataObjects-as-Pages

Thx and regards,
Florian

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I usually but together a custom search function after enabling `FulltextSearchable`. So in `_config.php` I would have

```
FulltextSearchable::enable();
Object::add_extension('NewsStory', "FulltextSearchable('Name,Content')");
```

replacing *Name* and *Content* with whatever `DBField` you want to be searchable. And each searchable `DataObject` have this in their class to enable search indexes (pretty sure this needs to be added and run dev/build before enabling the extension, and only works on MySQL DB).

```
static $create_table_options = array(
  'MySQLDatabase' => 'ENGINE=MyISAM'
);
```

then in my `PageController` I have my custom *searchForm* and *results* functions.

Here is the `search` function that returns the search form, called with `$search` in the template:

```php
public function search()
{       
  if($this->request && $this->request->requestVar('Search')) {
    $searchText = $this->request->requestVar('Search');
  }else{
    $searchText = 'Search';
  }

  $f = new TextField('Search', false, $searchText);

  $fields = new FieldList(
    $f
  );
  $actions = new FieldList(
    new FormAction('results', 'Go')
  );
  $form = new Form(
    $this,
    'search',
    $fields,
    $actions
  );
  //$form->disableSecurityToken();
  $form->setFormMethod('GET');
  $form->setTemplate('SearchForm');

  return $form;
}
```

and here the custom `results` function to handle the queries...

```php
function results($data, $form, $request)
{   
  $keyword = trim($request->requestVar('Search'));
  $keyword = Convert::raw2sql($keyword);
  $keywordHTML = htmlentities($keyword, ENT_NOQUOTES, 'UTF-8');    

  $pages = new ArrayList();
  $news = new ArrayList();

  $mode = ' IN BOOLEAN MODE';
  //$mode = ' WITH QUERY EXPANSION';
  //$mode = '';

  $siteTreeClasses = array('Page');
  $siteTreeMatch = "MATCH( Title, MenuTitle, Content, MetaTitle, MetaDescription, MetaKeywords ) AGAINST ('$keyword'$mode)
                  + MATCH( Title, MenuTitle, Content, MetaTitle, MetaDescription, MetaKeywords ) AGAINST ('$keywordHTML'$mode)";

  $newsItemMatch = "MATCH( Name, Content ) AGAINST ('$keyword'$mode)
                  + MATCH( Name, Content ) AGAINST ('$keywordHTML'$mode)";

  //Standard pages
  foreach ( $siteTreeClasses as $c )
  {
    $query = DataList::create($c)
      ->where($siteTreeMatch);
    $query = $query->dataQuery()->query();
    $query->addSelect(array('Relevance' => $siteTreeMatch));

    $records = DB::query($query->sql());
    $objects = array();
    foreach( $records as $record )
    {
      if ( in_array($record['ClassName'], $siteTreeClasses) )
        $objects[] = new $record['ClassName']($record);
    }
    $pages->merge($objects);
  }


  //news
  $query = DataList::create('NewsStory')->where($newsItemMatch);
  $query = $query->dataQuery()->query();
  $query->addSelect(array('Relevance' => $newsItemMatch));

  $records = DB::query($query->sql());
  $objects = array();
  foreach( $records as $record ) $objects[] = new $record['ClassName']($record);
  $news->merge($objects);


  //sorting results
  $pages->sort(array(
    'Relevance' => 'DESC',
    'Title' => 'ASC'
  ));      
  $news->sort(array(
    'Relevance' => 'DESC',
    'Date' => 'DESC'
  ));

  //output
  $data = array(
    'Pages' => $pages,
    'News' => $news,
    'Query' => $keyword
  ); 
  return $this->customise($data)->renderWith(array('Search','Page'));
}
```

I add all the *Page* classes I want to be searched and that extend `SiteTree` in the `$siteTreeClasses` array, and the *News* parts can be pretty much copied for any other `DataObject`I need searchable.

I am not saying this is the best solution and this can definitely be improved on, but it works for me and this might be a good stating point.

Comment: hey! i managed to do it more or less your way. I took the whole searchEngine function out of MySQLDatabase.php and adapted it: https://gist.github.com/4660526#file-page-php

Comment: how are you accessing the results in the search results template?

Comment: in this instance you can access the results with `$Pages` and `$News` in the template and use `<% loop XXX %>` to iterate over each result set.

Comment: oh yeah.  sorry i get it now.  Set in the $data.  Awesome this is such a good starting point to patch up my search page. Thanks colymba!

Answer (score 2):

I have adapted @colymba's solution into a silverstripe module: https://github.com/burnbright/silverstripe-pagesearch

It allows setting the pagetype in the url.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to substantially overwrite `SearchForm->getResults()`.
It uses `Database->searchEngine()`, but those are tailored towards `SiteTree` and `Page` classes.

The "proper" solution is to feed the data into a search engine like Solr or Sphinx.
We have the SS3-compatible "fulltextsearch" module for this purpose:
https://github.com/silverstripe-labs/silverstripe-fulltextsearch
It's going to take some upfront setup, and is only feasible if you can either host Solr yourself, or are prepared to pay for a SaaS provider. Once you've got it running though, the possibilities are endless, its a great tool!

Comment: hey ingo, i´m trying to overwrite the core classes SearchForm and MySQLDatabase. I created the classes CustomSearchForm and CustomMySQLDatabase extending these core classes. Then I added in config these lines: `Object::useCustomClass('SearchForm', 'CustomSearchForm', true);
Object::useCustomClass('MySQLDatabase', 'CustomMySQLDatabase', true);`
but still the core classes are used by silverstripe. how come? thx

Comment: Ingo. Are there any plans to improve the built in search? Considering the shinx / solr thing to be the silverstripe "proper" way to do search leaves a lot of us behind whose clients are no where near having unmanaged private servers.