# Silverstripe FulltextSearchable add custom fields

Tags: content-management-system, silverstripe

I need a custom field to be FulltextSearchable. Therefore I tried this code as described in the FulltextSearchable class:

```
Object::add_extension('Page', "FulltextSearchable('SearchableContent')");
```

then run dev/build.
Basically Fulltext Search seems to work. But the content of the custom Field 'SearchableContent' seems never to be checked.

Of course I enabled FulltextSearch first by:

```
FulltextSearchable::enable();
```

Thx,
Florian

Comment: This answer should help you you:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14483880/silverstripe-dataobject-searchable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All `SiteTree` classes have their search columns define in `FulltextSearchable` like:

```
$defaultColumns = array(
  'SiteTree' => '"Title","MenuTitle","Content","MetaTitle","MetaDescription","MetaKeywords"',
  'File' => '"Title","Filename","Content"'
);
```

so I don't think SilverStripe will pick up on your extra column. Unless you edit the `FulltextSearchable` but that's probably a bad idea... or just create a custom search function like for plain `DataObject` so you can specify exactly which columns to search on:
[silverstripe dataobject searchable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14483880/silverstripe-dataobject-searchable/14489700#14489700)

Comment: thank you. I tried to edit FulltextSearchable directly. but also that has no effect:

`$defaultColumns = array(
   'SiteTree' => 'Title,MenuTitle,Content,MetaTitle,MetaDescription,MetaKeywords,SearchableContent',
   'File' => 'Filename,Title,Content'
  );`
i did dev/build afterwards. 'SearchableContent' is still ignored...

Comment: that's the problem with the default `FulltextSearchable` a lot of it if not all is hard coded and specially designed for `File` and `SiteTree`. If am right, the `FulltextSearchable` only updates the engine used to create the DB tables, and the indexes.

Comment: So after some looking into, you would have to modify the `searchEngine` function in the `MySQLDatabase` class @ line 818 (called by the `ContentController` extension). But again this is _risky business_ and you would loose all of it when updating SilverStripe. Best, easiest and safest way is to overwrite the `results` function in you controller and write in you own query.

Comment: do you mean to add the extra field here: `$match['SiteTree'] = "
    MATCH (Title, MenuTitle, Content, MetaTitle, MetaDescription, MetaKeywords) AGAINST ('$keywords' $boolean)
    + MATCH (Title, MenuTitle, Content, MetaTitle, MetaDescription, MetaKeywords) AGAINST ('$htmlEntityKeywords' $boolean)`

the query runs on the SiteTree_Live table. so adding a Value to that lines causes an Error (value not found in where clause...). But the Custom Field that I added is found in the Page table.

Comment: sorry, it will actually throw an error because your extra column is in the `Page` table and the search is done on the `SiteTree` table. Best to leave those files alone anyway. But you can use this Gist: https://gist.github.com/4657819, paste the function in your `Page_Controller` class, this will override the default search function and add in DataObjects and custom Page columns (you'll have to edit some of it to match you setup). Then in you template you'll have access to the results via `$Pages`, `$News`, `$Files`...

Comment: thank you, cause I was under time pressure I misused the Meta Description Field to put the info that I wanted to use the custom field for. thats ok for now. but in the next project I need that again. I can use your pastie. it looks good. In the meantime I hope someone will code a nice search module that is easy to configure :)

Comment: glad you got your own function working.. I re-use that Gist myself for almost every project.. and was just thinking I should put an extension together for that...