# Site search for a silverstripe site without installing Sphinx

Tags: silverstripe

Silverstripe has a full text search facility built in. Its great, but it does not search related models, so a site search for a string that matches a records tags or article->author->name type relations will not be found.

The more advanced search modules rely on java and need to be installed. That isn't possible on our clients server and probably most regular hosting accounts (shared or VPS)

What is a good way to implement site search for a site with interrelated data in the form of many_many or has_many relations in silverstripe without a private server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something similar has been answered here [silverstripe dataobject searchable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14483880/silverstripe-dataobject-searchable/14489700#14489700)

It goes through customising the built in site search for DataObjects.

Comment: thanks colymba your answer over there looks good.  should that work with related data like finding a debatepage that has many_many panelists and the searchterm matches the panelist name?

Comment: It wont search relations by itself, but you can search through all the DataObject types you need, and then pull each one's relation as needed.

Answer (score 0):

currently going with google CSE for a silverstripe project:
https://developers.google.com/custom-search/
happy with this for now; just note that charges will apply if you want to remove the ads.