# How to make full site searchable in silverstripe?

Tags: silverstripe

How to make full site searchable in silverstripe.The defaults searches only the title and content but not the textfield.
Any help is accepted.

Comment: If you solved your issue please upvote the right answer, or post your solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out https://stackoverflow.com/a/14489700/494421 for searching custom DataObjects.

There is also a robust search module that uses Lucene under the hood: https://code.google.com/p/lucene-silverstripe-plugin/ There are many configuration options, including searching custom fields.

Answer (score 1):

Silverstripe does not permit to search in custom fields.

You can implement search on arbitrary Page fields and also on arbitrary DataObject pages using [zirak/searchable-dataobjects module](http://addons.silverstripe.org/add-ons/zirak/searchable-dataobjects).